# Locking in EntityFramework - calling empty stored procedure releases lock acquired using sp_getapplock

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a patient table in the SQL Server database. Clients connect to the database and checkout one of the patients and do some operations on it and save it afterwards.

Since multiple clients might access the patient at the same time. I wanted to implement pessimistic locking mechanism, So that if one client can acquire a lock to a particular patient at a time.

Also if one of the clients locks a particular patient and either crashes or closes the client application the lock should be released. In case of crash the lock should be released when we detect that the connection of client with the database is closed.

I found out that I could use `sp_getapplock` and `sp_releaseapplock` to do achieve this and specify `@LockOwner = 'Session'` when calling `sp_getapplock`, this ensures that the lock is released once the database session with the client closes.

From the code, I call a stored procedure in database to acquire the lock. This acquires the lock correctly and if i close off the client app or the client app crashes the lock is released. This is behaving as I wanted it to.

The problem happens when I call another stored procedure which is supposed to release the lock. As soon as the stored procedure is entered the lock is released, before we even execute `sp_releaseapplock @patientId, @LockOwner = 'Session'` the line which is actually supposed to release the lock.

I tried creating an empty stored procedure (just commented out

```
DECLARE @result int
EXEC @result = sp_releaseapplock @patientId, @LockOwner = 'Session'
```

This stored procedure still releases the lock I acquired using `sp_getapplock`. I can't seem to understand why this is happening. It should only release when I explicitly call `sp_releaseapplock @patientId, @LockOwner = 'Session'``

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspReleaseAppLock]
    @patientId nvarchar(max),               -- Patient ID
    @ReturnValue int Output
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @result int
   EXEC @result = sp_releaseapplock @patientId, @LockOwner = 'Session'
   SET @ReturnValue = @@SPID
END
```

Could someone tell me why this is happening. What am I missing here ? I checked that the session ids of both the stored procedures (for acquiring and releasing the lock) are same, so it dose not seem that a new session is being created by entity frame work for each call to the stored procedure. Something else is going on which I am not able to comprehend. Any ideas ?

Comment: Why do you think you need pessimistic locking? SQL Server is optimized for **optimistic** locking, and I never felt the need to do something else - even in very busy systems with hundreds of concurrent users.....

Comment: @marc_s Its the the nature of the application. The client checkouts the patient and does some analysis on it and saves it later on. I don't want someone to check it out and do analysis only to find out that results cant be saved back to database, because data has been changed by someone else, it takes time in the application to do analysis and all this will be wasted. That is why i want to be absolutely sure that if someone checks out a patient has exclusive access to it. I don't think this can be done using optimistic locking.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, so you've probably figured out something, but I feel compelled to answer anyways.  To me you're trying to do application level logic at the data storage level.  I think what I would do is put a CheckedOut bit flag on the record.  Then when a user checks out the patient, the flag is set to true.  The application would check to make sure that the flag was false before allowing another user to check it out.  Once the original users check the patient back in the flag is set back to false along with any changes.

Just an idea.

Comment: Even if we were to just use a flag here, there would be a risk that two users could somehow request the patient when the flag was set to false and end up in an undesirable state.